# When should I use CREATE and when MERGE in Cypher queries?

Tags: memgraphdb, opencypher

I've seen that sometimes `CREATE` is used to create nodes, and in other situations, `MERGE` is used. What's the difference, and when should one be used in place of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE` does just what it says. It creates, and if that means creating duplicates, well then it creates.

`MERGE` does the same thing as `CREATE`, but also checks to see if a node already exists with the properties you specify. If it does, then it doesn't create. This helps avoid duplicates.

Here's an example: I use `CREATE` twice to create a person with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE` should be used when you are absolutely certain that the information doesn't exist in the database (for example, when you are loading data). `MERGE` is used whenever there is a possibility that the node or relationship already exists and you don’t need to duplicate it. `MERGE` shouldn't always be used as it’s considerably slower than the create clause.